# A son or The son ( Articles)

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

1. ***A*** son of my friend suggested me this.

OR

2. ***The*** son of my friend suggested me this.

My doubt is that if I used "the son" then wouldn't the listener ask which son am I talking about because I have never introduced this son in the first place and if I use "a son", is he going to think that my friend has multiple sons?

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/usage-of-article-the-the-son-of-austrlian-immigrants). If you are only mentioning your friend's son in passing and the listener doesn't know your friend, they would have no reason to ask for further details about him. If his identity is important you would probably say "Peter, my friend Mary's youngest, suggested..."

Comment: " a son of friend" does this have any implication that my friend has multiple sons?

Comment: Yes, it could do - but, again, not important unless the son's identity is relevant to the conversation.